# .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/152058/htaccess-file)
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

I am looking for exact code for creating .htaccess file used for redirect a simple static page.

Looking forward to positive replies.

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't get much simpler than this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo.html$ /bar.html [R=301]
```

The effect of this would be users who try to access `foo.html` getting redirected to `bar.html` (with the HTTP response code 301).

Comment: Yes it does. `Redirect permanent /foo.html /bar.html`

Comment: "much" redefined